# What is the name of this twisting structure at kids playground?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, british-english, image-identification

We can usually find this structure at kids playgrounds. I want to know what it's called.

I've searched online but couldn't figure it out but fortunately found the image below.

[image: a freestanding spiral slide]

Comment: If you found the image [here](http://www.davebang.com/independent_play.iml?Category=2), then the caption says it all: "360 Spiral Slide". The file is also similarly named.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have said, that is a picture of a *spiral slide*.

I only wanted to point out that there would be nothing wrong with calling it a *slide* either. If my daughter said, "Daddy, can I go play on the slide?" I would certainly *not* correct her with, "That's not a *slide*, that's a [*vortex slide*](http://www.google.com/search?q=vortex%20slide&hl=en&rls=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch)." However, if I was a park manager wanting to order a slide like that one for my playground, I wouldn't ask to order a *slide*, but I would specify that I wanted a *plastic spiral slide*.

*Slides* come in many variations, including spiral slides, tube slides, indoor slides, playground slides, pools slides and water slides.

[image]

Comment: +1 Due to their clarity, I love answers supported with pictures.

Comment: Let's not forget carpet slides.  :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a spiral slide to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to order one for your own garden, then *spiral slide* is obviously the right term.

As far as children's names for such a thing are concerned, as well as "slide" it could easily be a *helter-skelter* because of its similarity to the fairground attraction (which are usually a lot larger!)

[image: Helter-skelter attraction at a fairground]

<sup>Image from http://www.ukstudentlife.com/Ideas/Album/Village-Fete.htm</sup>

Comment: Helter-skelter appears as holterdipolter (if I remember correctly) in German and ulta-palta in Hindi.

Answer (score 2):

I would also call it a spiral slide. Alternative would be a corkscrew slide
http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=corkscrew+OR+spiral+slide